# Replace text in MySql database

Tags: mysql, database, character-encoding, phpmyadmin

I have a MySql database on my server with a table named table_1. However I imported a csv file which occasionally included "café". However the "é" was not inserted into the database table, so I have been left with the text "caf". So what I would like to know is how can I replace the word "caf" in my database table with "cafe"?

Comment: You need to deal with the collation setting at either the table or database level first to ensure the collation is setup.

Comment: You can't fix this after the fact. What if your db has caffinated in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like an encoding issue to me - make sure you're using UTF-8 throughout your DB, and reimport your CSV.

If you've used the [LOAD DATA](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) command in MySQL, you can pass it a CHARACTER SET, which, when set to 'utf8' should allow you to import that file correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem of encoding. I sugest that you change your mysql database to utf-8 via GUI or [with this information](http://www.oreillynet.com/onlamp/blog/2006/01/turning_mysql_data_in_latin1_t.html)